# Is it possible in Next.js to pass data from getStaticProps to contextProvider and set it as default useReducer value?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state, react-context, use-reducer

In my *pages/index.js* there is getStaticProps function which fetches list of articles (I'm creating a blog website) which is then used as an init value of my useReducer that is located in the same file. I'm using useReducer to do some basic sorting and filtering on the client side. I want to slim down my *index.js* page as well as switch from prop drilling to context API by moving useReducer logic into new context provider file.

I tried to create two files inside *context* folder: *articles-context.js* and *ArticlesProvider.js*. In *ArticlesProvider.js* I put all useReducer logic, but I cannot figure how to pass data from *index.js* to *ArticlesProvider.js* and use that data as initial useReducer value in order to utilize context API in my articles component and display list of articles instantly after loading the page. Is it even possible to manage state like this or is there much better way, or should I just stay with state management in my *index.js* file?

*index.js* looks like this right now:

```
*recuder...*

const Home = ({ articles }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    articlesList: articles,
    filterValue: '',
  });

*functions dispatching actions...*
}

*getStaticProps function*
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned by `getStaticProps` is passed as props to the page. And this same props is accessible in _app.js.
so from _app.js you can pass it to `contextProvider` :

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      articles: {} //
      toContextProvider: {first: "val1", second: "val2"}
    },
  };
}
```

Then in `MyApp` you can recieve the passed data :

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(pageProps.toContextProvider);
 //...
}
```